# Entity Data Model Wizard not showing Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 in vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I have SQL Compact 3.5 edition for which I am trying to generate an EDMX file using the Entity data model wizard. I am using Visual Studio 2012 Beta Ultimate.

I am trying to generate a Model (generate from the database). I create a new connection, selecting the change data source. Here I am not able to see *Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5* database file.

But I could see this in VS 2010.

How do I do to create an entity model with SQL CE 3.5 and Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 is not supported with Server Explorer etc in VS 2012.

**UPDATE** The latest version of the free SQL Server Compact Toolbox addin adds support for connecting SQL Server Compact 3.5 files to Server Explorer for working with the Entity Framework Tools

Comment: Eric what's the alternative for it, Any suggestions.

Comment: You could upgrade your database to 4.0, then everything would work with VS 2012 - or stay at VS 2010 with your project...

Comment: Thanks Eric for your comments.i had to stay with sql ce 3.5 since i am using Microsoft Sync (which is generating .sdf file in 3.5 version only) what i did was generate an EDMX file in vs 2010 and copied into my visual studio 2012,copied the connection string to App.config file. then i was able to query the model.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you need VS 2012 for your project?

Comment: With the new Features,Code suggestions & since 2012 projects are backword compatible to vs2010, we are just giving it a try.

Comment: So @ErikEJ, if I have a file generated with SQL Server Compact 3.5 this answer implies that I cannot connect to it as a data source in Visual Studio 2012. Is that right? If so that answers my question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13066973/575530), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/d1f38b1a-8c51-4332-967b-576b24b75d58), and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/4018bbde-a460-4500-abc0-2abaa6ad3fa2)). It's a shame, I was hoping not to need to run VS2010 side-by-side with 2012.

Comment: Over on [one of the other threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/d1f38b1a-8c51-4332-967b-576b24b75d58) [Ray Chen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/shulei%20chen/) gave an excellent answer including a link to @ErikEJ's blog post [HOW TO: Upgrade a version 3.x database file to SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html) and to the [SqlCeEngine.Upgrade Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896160.aspx) library page.