# How can I connect to a SQL Server Compact 3.5 file as a data source in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce-3.5

Visual Studio 2012 comes with SQL Server Compact 4.0. I have installed SQL Server Compact 3.5 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5783 However I still only have the option of making a new data connection to a SQL Server Compact 4.0 file, whereas the files I need to get data from are SQL Server Compact 3.5 files.

[image]

Is it possible to connect to a SQL Server Compact 3.5 file as a data source in Visual Studio 2012? If so which settings or installs should I need?

Comment: I may have just stumbled upon the same question (though put differently) in which case the sad [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10936459/575530) (from [ErikEJ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej)) is "SQL Server Compact 3.5 is not supported with Server Explorer etc in VS 2012".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over in [a thread I started](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/d1f38b1a-8c51-4332-967b-576b24b75d58) on SQL Server Developer Center >  SQL Server Forums >  SQL Server Compact [Ray Chen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/shulei%20chen/) has posted an answer:

> Unfortunately, SQL Server CE 3.5 is not supported in VS 2012 indeed.
>   You have to upgrade the SQL Server CE 3.5 database to 4.0 as [Erik
>   suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10936459/575530) [link added]. Also please take a look at this article:  [Visual Studio
>   2012
>   Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx#attention).
>   In the section of ‘These Assets Need Your Attention’, it says: One-way
>   upgrade. You must upgrade these assets before you can open them in
>   Visual Studio 2012. After you upgrade, you won’t be able to open them
>   in previous versions. The following table lists the project types,
>   file types, and technologies that you must upgrade. And SQL Server CE
>   3.5 is included in the table.

I've posted a subsidiary question there to find out how, given that I cannot read in the file, I would convert it to SQL Server Compact 4.0.

=========== EDIT ==========

[Ray Chen](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/shulei%20chen/) went on to post references to [ErikEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej)'s blog post [HOW TO: Upgrade a version 3.x database file to SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/how-to-upgrade-version-3x-database-file.html) and to the [SqlCeEngine.Upgrade Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896160.aspx) library page.